# Using Redgate Reflector tool, what does it mean when some class names are light grey?

Tags: reflector, redgate

I'm using Reflector and can see some class names are black and others are light grey.

I tried doing a search for what this means and could not find a user guide or anything to indicate what this means.

[image: example of lighter font]

I'm wondering if it might be related to the public/private of the class? I'm also assuming the envelope means sealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black are public and the gray are not public (so they could be internal, private, etc.).

If you go to the Tools Menu -> Options and choose the Browser item, you can change the Visibility dropdown to show "Public Items Only".  Then click Ok, all the gray items will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the gray classes are `internal`.  Compare [SafeNCryptHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safencrypthandle.aspx), a `public` `abstract` class, with [SafeBcryptHashHandle](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Core/Microsoft/Win32/SafeHandles/BCryptSafeHandles@cs/1305376/BCryptSafeHandles@cs), an`internal` `sealed` class that has no publicly documented API.

Comment: I found some private variables that also show up gray/grey. I still think its related to if the node is visible publicly or not.